# How do I assign a dataframe to itself when starting a pipe in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Very often, I have to manipulate a data.frame through a chain of `dplyr` statements and then assign the result of the pipe to the original data.frame.

Example:
`df <- df %>% .....`

Since I have the habit of naming my variables with long explicit names, this additional keystrokes might eat into my productivity a bit. I would believe there has to be a shortcut to assign a data.frame to itself without repeating oneself like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't. If you're using a decent IDE, it should suggest you a name anyway.

Comment: There's the magrittr [assignment pipe](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/compound.html).

Comment: @RuiBarradas, this is exactly what I wanted. Can you make this comment into an answer?

Comment: It would be a link only answer, a reason to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably looking for `%<>%`:

```r
require(dplyr)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
require(magrittr)
#> Loading required package: magrittr
df<-data.frame(a=1:2)
df %<>% mutate(a=a*2)
df
#>   a
#> 1 2
#> 2 4
```

Comment: loading only `dplyr` doesn't work. I also have to explicitly load `magrittr` as well.